# Custom line-spacing inside a footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes, line-spacing

I know I can use the following command to set the spacing in footnotes throughout the document to double space:

```
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}
```

But is there a way to allow for custom spacing in footnotes throughout the document? So, e.g. I’d like to achieve the spacing effect of `\linespread{1.6}` in footnotes, throughout - is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `\footnote{\baselineskip1.5\baselineskip footnote text}`

Comment: Right, but won’t this require me to type the command at the beginning of every footnote? I’m looking for a way to make it hold throughout the whole document at once.

Comment: Ok, in this case `\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\baselineskip1.5\baselineskip}`

Comment: The only problem is that this keeps the spacing between the last line of a footnote and the first line of the next footnote as set by default, rather then as specified by the custom spacing.

Comment: try `\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\baselineskip1.5\baselineskip\footnotesep2\footnotesep}`